# If I terminate the process, the thread would also stop?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-3.4, python-multithreading

I've following code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import subprocess
import time
import threading


class StartJar(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        os.system("java -jar <nazwa_appki>.jar")

jarFileRun = StartJar        
current_location = subprocess.getoutput("pwd")

while True:
    x = subprocess.getstatusoutput("git checkout master && git reset --hard && git fetch && git pull")
    if x[0] is 0:
        os.system("git checkout master && git reset --hard && git fetch && git pull")
        os.system("mvn clean package ~/your/path")

        try:
            process_pid = subprocess.check_output(['pgrep', '-f', 'tu_podaj_nazwe_procesu']).decode()
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            print("pgrep failed because ({}):".format(e.returncode), e.output.decode())
        else:
            try:
                os.kill(int(process_pid), 9)
                print('Process with ' + process_pid + ' PID was killed.')
            except ProcessLookupError as e:
                print("Process were old...")
            except ValueError as e:
                print("There is no such process!")

        os.system("cp ~/your/path" + ' ' + current_location)
        jarFileRun.start()
    else:
        print('No changes was made...')

time.sleep(1800)
```

And I wonder if I kill process that my thread runs, it would close as well ? If no how do i terminate the thread to be able to run it once more with new changes that had came out for the file I want to execute ?
I tried to find out in google something that stops thread but it didn't work for me when I added it to the first line of while statement.

Comment: Yes.  The tread runs inside the process, if the process dies, then so does the thread within it.  But that's easy enough to test yourself.

Comment: Why are you running java as a thread, why not just run it as a background process?

Answer (score 0):

If you terminate the process,all threads corresponding to that process would terminate. the process will still run if you terminate one of the threads in process.

Answer (score -1):

No it will not terminate because the value `daemon` is by default False and it means that the thread doesn't stop when the main process finishes, it's totally independent. However, if you set the thread's daemon value to `True` it will run as long as the main process runs too.

In order to do so you can delete your `StartJar` class and define `jarFileRun`
like this:

```
jarFileRun = threading.Thread(target=os.system, args=("java -jar <nazwa_appki>.jar",), daemon=True)
```

Or make an init definition inside the class for `daemon`

Comment: Can I add it to run function or should I add __init__?